# Realm Android : Add realmobject as sub array in datamodel class

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have data model class in kotlin android,  i want to update the database when the app is in online, my model class look like this

```
open class seller_dataRealmclass : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    var id: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    var email: String? = null
    @SerializedName("seller_type")
    @Expose
    var sellerType: Boolean? = false
    @SerializedName("location")
    @Expose
    var location: String? = null
    @SerializedName("depot_id")
    @Expose
    var depotId: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("sbl_no")
    @Expose
    var sblNo: String? = null
    @SerializedName("selling_frequency")
    @Expose
    var sellingFrequency: Boolean? = null
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    var address: String? = null
    @SerializedName("gstn")
    @Expose
    var gstn: String? = null
    @SerializedName("cr_no")
    @Expose
    var crNo: String? = null
    @SerializedName("aadhar_no")
    @Expose
    var aadharNo: String? = null
    @SerializedName("active")
    @Expose
    var active: Boolean? = null
    @SerializedName("deleted")
    @Expose
    var deleted: Boolean? = null
    @SerializedName("created")
    @Expose
    var created: String? = null
    @SerializedName("modified")
    @Expose
    var modified: String? = null
    @SerializedName("seller_accounts")
    @Expose
    var sellerAccounts: RealmList<SellerAccount>? = null
    @SerializedName("seller_mobiles")
    @Expose
    var sellerMobiles: RealmList<SellerMobile>? = null
}
```

In this model class, I also do have a separate real object, which is  SellerAccount and SellerMobile, I initialise it as RealmList because the data from the server are returning as JSON array format

When I try to retrieve data like this

```
var seller_realm=mRealm?.createObjectFromJson(seller_dataRealmclass::class.java,seller_object.toString() )
```

most of the values are null and the seller account, SellerMobile are not being saved, I try to declare it as an array but the realm does not support array format inside the table

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using GSON to deserialize the object and then save it to Realm by hand instead of with `createObjectFromJson`?

Comment: He i finally come to solve that issues                                                              var seller_object = Sellers.getJSONObject(i).toString()
var seller_realm=mRealm?.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(seller_dataRealmclass::class.java,seller_object)